# Auto-scaling load balanced EC2 instances by example

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-application-load-balancer, aws-auto-scaling

I am reading up on [AWS Auto Scaling Groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/auto-scaling-groups.html) and trying to understand (from a network-perspective) how the following resources all fit together:

- Auto Scaling Group (ASG)
- Application Load Balancer (ALB)
- Individual EC2 instances sitting behind the ALB
- ALB Listeners
- ALB Target Groups
- Security Group(s) enforcing which IPs/ports are allowed access to the EC2 instances

I understand what each of these does in theory, but in practice, I'm having trouble seeing the forest through the trees with how they all snap together. For example: do I configure the EC2 instances to be members of the Security Group? Or do I do that at the balancer-level? If I attach the ALB to the Auto Scaling Group, then why would I need to do any additional configuration with an ALB Target Group? When it comes to routing, do I route port 80 traffic to the ALB or the Auto Scale Group?

I know these are lots of small questions, so the main question here is: how do all of these snap together to provide a load balanced web server hosted on EC2 instances? Ultimately I need to configure all of this inside a CloudFormation template, but a diagram or explanation to help me configure everything manually is probably the best place for me to start. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> do I configure the EC2 instances to be members of the Security Group?
> Or do I do that at the balancer-level?

The EC2 instances should be a member of one security group. The Load Balancer should be a member of another security group. The Load Balancer's security group should allow incoming traffic from the Internet. The EC2 instances should allow incoming traffic from the load balancer.

> If I attach the ALB to the Auto Scaling Group, then why would I need
> to do any additional configuration with an ALB Target Group?

If you are using an auto-scaling group to create the instances, then you don't have to do any manual updates to the target group, the auto-scaling group will handle those updates for you.

> When it comes to routing, do I route port 80 traffic to the ALB or the
> Auto Scale Group?

An Auto-scaling group is not a resource that exists in your network. It is a construct within AWS that just creates/removes EC2 servers for you based on metrics. The traffic goes to the load balancer, and the load balancer sends it to the EC2 instances in the target group.

> I know these are lots of small questions, so the main question here is: how do all of these snap together to provide a load balanced web server hosted on EC2 instances? Ultimately I need to configure all of this inside a CloudFormation template, but a diagram or explanation to help me configure everything manually is probably the best place for me to start.

It's a bit much to ask somebody on here to spend their free time creating a diagram for you. I suggest looking at the AWS reference WordPress implementations which they tend to use for providing reference implementations of auto-scaled web server environments.

See the "WordPress scalable and durable" CloudFormation template example [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/sample-templates-applications-us-east-2.html).

See the AWS WordPress Reference Architecture project [here](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-refarch-wordpress), which includes a diagram.

Comment: Thanks again @Mark B (+1), and understood about the diagram, and agreed (!). After reading your response I'm thinking, in terms of "orders of operation": (1) instantiate the EC2 instances, (2) create a Securty Group to manage traffic to them, (3) create the ALB, listener and target group and have the ALB point to the EC2 instances, and then (4) create the auto scaling group and attach the ALB to it. Is that the general order of operations for this kind of setup? Am I missing anything major? Thanks again!

Comment: No, you don't instantiate the EC2 instances at all if you are using an auto-scaling group. You let it create them for you. You tell the auto-scaling group the information about the instances you want it to run, and how many, and it does that for you. If anything you might need to create an instance once to create an AMI from it, which the auto-scaling group will then use to create your actual instances. You also left out some steps like creating the security group for the load balancer, but really I highly suggest you look at those references I linked.